# TypeError-'function' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, random, average, typeerror

I have a program where by a teahcer can view the her student's squiz results and sort them in a avruiety way:

```
if role == 2:
class_number = prompt_int_big("Which class' scores would you like to see? Press 1 for class 1, 2 for class 2 or 3 for class 3")
filename = (str(class_number) + "txt")
sort_or_not = prompt_int_small("Would youlike to sort these scores in any way? Press 1 if the answer is no or 2 if the answer is yes")
if sort_or_not == 1:
    f = open(filename, "r")
    lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
    lines.sort()
    for line in lines:
        print (line)
if sort_or_not == 2:
    type_of_sort = prompt_int_big("How would you like to sort these scores? Press 1 for scores in alphabetical order with each student's highest score for the tests, 2 if you would like to see the students' highest scores sorted from highest to lowest and 3 if you like to see these student's average scores sorted from highest to lowest")
    if type_of_sort == 1:
        with open(filename , 'r') as r:
            for line in sorted(r):
                print(line, end='')
    if type_of_sort == 2:
        with open (filename,'r') as r:
            def score(line):
                return int(line.split(':')[1])
            for line in sorted(r, key=score, reverse = True):
                print(line)
    if type_of_sort == 3:
        with open (filename,'r') as r:
            def score(line):
                returnint(line.split(':')[1])
            average = sum(map(int, score))/len(score)
            print(name,"--",average)
```

However when the third option is selected an error comes up:

```
average = sum(map(int, score))/len(score)
TypeError-'function' object is not iterable
```

Comment: If your going to down vote at least say why

Comment: The downvote means,  exact quote from SO when a user downvote: "This question does not any research effort, it is unclear or not useful". In such case, my best advice would be: please take a moment to read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

[`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) in Python-3.x returns an iterator (unlike Python-2.x where it returns a list of the result). Hence, you need to generate the list from the iterator and then pass it to the `sum()` function.

```
average = sum(list(map(int, score)))/len(score)
```

In the above, example `score` should be *iterable* like a list or a tuple.

**EDIT:** Well, map takes an *iterable* as an argument (like list, tuple) but in this case the argument passed, `score`, is a function. And you are passing the function name and not calling the function. Hence, a function gets passed to the `map()` function. So, you need to call the function. Eg:

```
score_list = score(r.readline())
average = sum(list(map(int, score_list)))/len(score_list)
```